# Typescript interface for objects with some known and some unknown property names

Tags: typescript

I have an object where all the keys are string, some of the values are string and the rest are objects in this form:

```
var object = {
    "fixedKey1": "something1",
    "fixedKey2": "something2",
    "unknownKey1": { 'param1': [1,2,3], 'param2': "some2", 'param3': 'some3'},
    "unknownKey2": { 'param1': [1,2,3], 'param2': "some2", 'param3': 'some3'},
    "unknownKey3": { 'param1': [1,2,3], 'param2': "some2", 'param3': 'some3'},
    ...
    ...
};
```

In this object `fixedKey1` and `fixedKey2` are the known keys which will be there in that object. `unknownKey` - value pair can vary from 1-n.

I tried defining the interface of the object as:

```
interface IfcObject {
    [keys: string]: {
        param1: number[];
        param2: string; 
        param3: string;
  }
}
```

But this throws the following error:

> Variable of type number is not assignable of type object

Which I found out that it is not able to assign this interface to "fixedKey - value" pair.

So, how can I do the type checking of this kind of variables?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It's not exactly what you want, but you can use a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html):

```
interface IfcObject {
    fixedKey1: string
    fixedKey2: string
    [key: string]: string | {
        param1: number[];
        param2: string; 
        param3: string;
    }
}
```

It covers your case. But the unknown properties could be of type `string`.

Answer (score 15):

```
export interface IfcObjectValues {
    param1: number[];
    param2: string;
    param3: string;        
}

interface MyInterface {
  fixedKey1: string,
  fixedKey2: number,
  [x: string]: IfcObjectValues, 
}
```

Your code in action, [see here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20MyInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20fixedKey1%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20fixedKey2%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%5Bx%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20object%3A%20MyInterface%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22fixedKey1%22%3A%20%22something1%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22fixedKey2%22%3A%20%22something2%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22unknownKey1%22%3A%20%7B%20%27param1%27%3A%20%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%2C%20%27param2%27%3A%20%22some2%22%2C%20%27param3%27%3A%20%27some3%27%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22unknownKey2%22%3A%20%7B%20%27param1%27%3A%20%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%2C%20%27param2%27%3A%20%22some2%22%2C%20%27param3%27%3A%20%27some3%27%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22unknownKey3%22%3A%20%7B%20%27param1%27%3A%20%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%2C%20%27param2%27%3A%20%22some2%22%2C%20%27param3%27%3A%20%27some3%27%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A).

Comment: Property 'fixedKey2' of type 'number' is not assignable to string index type 'IfcObjectValues'. This occurs in TypeScript 2.8.3.

Comment: This won't work, unless you type the unknown properties as `any`

Comment: This won't work, unless you type the unknown properties as `unknown`

Comment: This is not a correct answer, and the linked playground does not reflect the code posted here.

Answer (score 13):

As [@Paleo explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38262343), you can use union property to define an interface for your corresponding object.

I would say you should define an interface for object values and then you should define your original object.

Sample interface can be:

```
export interface IfcObjectValues {
    param1: number[];
    param2: string;
    param3: string;        
}

export interface IfcMainObject {
 [key : string]: string | IfcObjectValues;
}
```