# Typescript declaration for type with only one string property, and the rest number

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to declare a type in TypeScript that has only one property of a given type, and an [arbitrary number of properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38260414/typescript-interface-for-objects-with-some-known-and-some-unknown-property-names) of another type? For example, I want an object with a `name` string, then some numeric properties (but no other string properties):

```
type Foo = {
  name: string;
  [key: string]: number;
}
```

The problem with the declaration above is that `tsc` [emits](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?noImplicitAny=false&strictNullChecks=false&strictFunctionTypes=false&strictPropertyInitialization=false&strictBindCallApply=false&noImplicitThis=false&noImplicitReturns=false&alwaysStrict=false&esModuleInterop=false&declaration=false&target=99#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFKA7AhgWwgC4oBnYAJwEtsBzAbkygG0BrCEE86ugXROwBXfACMIFRgF90QA) this error:

> Property 'name' of type 'string' is not assignable to string index type 'number'.(2411)

I could change line 3 to `[key: string]: number | string;` but that allows the other properties to be strings, which I don't want.