# Typescript - How to type unknown properties of an object?

Tags: typescript

Suppose there is a variable `resp` receiving a response from the server:

```js
const resp = await ServerResponse();
```

I know for sure that the response has a `ready: boolean` property:

```js
console.log(resp);
/**
 * {
 *   "ready": true
 * }
 */
```

But there may be optional parameters, the type of which I do not know

```js
console.log(resp);
/**
 * {
 *   "ready": true,
 *   "_startAt": 1234567890
 * }
 */
```

How should I type this?

```
interface R {
  ready: boolean;
  //...args: any; //something like this
}
const resp: R = await ServerResponse();
```

Or there is another way, without giving `any` to the `resp` variable, so that when accessing unknown properties, TS does not swear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, we can make the value of the indexed property a loose type **any**

```
interface R{
  name: string;
  age: number;
  [prop: string]: any; // but this defeats the purpose of providing good typing.
}
```

Another approach would be to make additionalProperties a Dictionary

```
interface R {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  additionalProperties: { [prop: string]: string}; 
}
```

more you can check here as well
***[Typescript interface for objects with some known and some unknown property names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38260414/typescript-interface-for-objects-with-some-known-and-some-unknown-property-names)***

Comment: more you can read here 
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20597